# why wont my password work so i can upload the keypair to a bitnami Lamp in vbox

Tags: virtual, bitnami

I have loaded up a copy of bitnami lamp on a virtualbox running on my linux pc. I am hoping to be able to develop/test on my laptop before copying the changes to a virtual box running on AWS. I am trying to set up putty with a keyvalue pair. I have created the .ppk file I then I ran putty gen to create a .pub file. I am trying to upload this to the local vbox lamp server.

I have tried using ssh-copy-I'd to do the transfer. But I get a prompt for the Lamp servers password. That keeps failing. I can get into the vbox lamp server through the vboxs client. But when I use ssh-copy, it fails. How can I get the correct password to use.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

If you are using a Bitnami VM, you do not need to create a SSH key to access the VM. Once the VM is running, you will need to start the SSH service

```
sudo rm -f /etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run
sudo systemctl enable ssh
sudo systemctl start ssh
```

and access the server using the password you set when booting the VM

```
ssh bitnami@VM-IP
```

Please note that the VM's password (the one of the bitnami user in the command line) is not the same one than the app and database's password (this one is randomly generated)